# How do I get my templated bubbleSort() function to display a sorted vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

The `bubblesort()` function I have for my vector, fails to return a sorted version of the vector; there are times where if I do compile and execute the code in VS it gives me a runtime error when the function is called:

> Expression: vector subscript out of range

I've double checked the range, and it seems alright to me; I'm unsure what the issue is: I did make sure the vector was passed by reference.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

template <class T>
void fillVector(std::vector<T>& vobj, int n);

template <class T>
void displayVector(std::vector<T>& vobj);

template <class T>
void bubbleSort(std::vector<T>& vobj);
```

```cpp
template <class T>
void fillVector(std::vector<T>& vobj, int n)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        vobj.push_back(rand());
    }
}

template <class T>
void displayVector(std::vector<T>& vobj)
{
    const unsigned displayLimit = 10;
    if (vobj.size()>displayLimit)
    {
        for (unsigned i=0; i<displayLimit; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "  " << vobj[i];
        }
        std::cout << "  ..." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < vobj.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << vobj[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

```cpp
template <class T>
void bubbleSort(std::vector<T>& vobj)
{
    bool swapped = true;
    for (unsigned i=0; swapped && i<vobj.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (unsigned j=0; j<vobj.size()-1-i; ++j)
        {
            if (vobj[j]>vobj[j++])
            {
                swapped = true;
                std::swap(vobj[j],vobj[j++]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vobj;

    std::cout << "Enter # of objects you'd like to store in the vector object: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "\n*** Calling fillVector(...) ***" << std::endl;
    fillVector(vobj,n);
    std::cout << "\n*** Calling displayVector(...) ***" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector object contains " << n << " value(s) which are" << std::endl;
    displayVector(vobj);

    std::cout << "\n*** Calling bubbleSort(...) ***" << std::endl;
    bubbleSort(vobj);
    displayVector(vobj);
}
```

Comment: These functions all return **`void`**. There is no way to make that sort function return a sorted array. Also, the code seems to be working with vectors, not arrays.

Comment: The VS debugger will tell you exactly where the problem is.  However, I suspect that `if (vobj[j]>vobj[j++])` and the similar use in `swap` a few lines lower is the reason for the problem.

Comment: *I've double checked the range, and it seems alright to me* -- The computer is the one telling the truth.  You're only speculating or using error-prone eyeballing the code.  Also, when posting code, remove the comments from the code.  We all know what declarations do, so no need to flood the question with unnecessary commented code.

Comment: Also in Visual Studio, there is a "Retry" option, saying specifically to press "Retry" to debug the application.  Did you do that?  If you did, the call stack will show exactly what the issue is

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ye i know my professor left those in there for the function prototypes; i was arguing with myself if i should remove them when i posted it here cause it is obvious what each function does; i did press retry but the alert kept nagging me, will check the call stack to see

Comment: @S.Coughing I don't know how familiar with the debugger you are, but you can also look at the values in all your variables (moving up and down the call stack as needed) once you break in.  That will show what's really happening.  Just make sure you're running a Debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `bubbleSort` routine you increment the `j` variable 3 times! Don't you think that is twice too many?

```
if (vobj[j]>vobj[j++])
```

should be

```
if (vobj[j]>vobj[j+1])
```

and

```
std::swap(vobj[j],vobj[j++]);
```

should be

```
std::swap(vobj[j],vobj[j+1]);
```

Incrementing a variable is not the same as adding one to it.

Comment: this has solved my problem, but i'm having an issue understanding: `Incrementing a variable is not the same as adding one to it.`

Comment: If you increment a variable `j++` (or `++j`) you change the value of the variable `j`, if you add one to a variable `j + 1` you don't change the value of the variable `j`.